# What does somestring1_somestring2:metric_name:some_operation mean in prometheus query language

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am trying to understand default prometheus rules for kubernetes. And then I came across with this expression:

```
      sum(namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum{})
        /
      sum(kube_node_status_allocatable{resource="cpu"})
        >
      ((count(kube_node_status_allocatable{resource="cpu"}) > 1) - 1) / count(kube_node_status_allocatable{resource="cpu"})
```

Specifically, i am curious at `namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum{}`. namespace_cpu does not appear to be an operation or reserved word in promql.

I can't seem to find it either in Prometheus documentation. https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing, it's not an operator `:` is just a legal character in metric names. Some standard rulesets use it for grouping rollup rules together but it's just a naming scheme at most.

Comment: I see. I guess the :sum at the end is also part of the metric name then. Thank you!

Comment: Yep, naming scheme again, indicating the type of rollup since you'll sometimes see different types or time ranges.